# Matplotlib: Display a scatter plot on top of an image with the right ordering and size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some coordinates that I want to display on top of an image with the right size and axes labels. The coordinates, which run from -750 to +750 on the X-axis and -400 to +450 (not +400) on the Y-axis, look like this:

```
[('-397.91', '58.91'), ('-569.73', '179.18'), ('-461.73', '306.82'), ('-199.09', '186.55'), ('-348.82', '-169.36'), ('-125.45', '-243.00'), ('4.64', '-267.55'), ('110.18', '-265.09'), ('267.27', '-12.27'), ('-687.55', '390.27')]
```

The image to be used as the background is as follows:

[image: Background image to be used]

The intended result is something like this: (There is a ball in the top-left pocket in addition to the nine visible on-screen.)

[image: Actual picture]

For this I have written the following.

```
#Conversion of dataframe to array of tuples:
plotdata = list(data.to_records(index=False)) #data is the dataframe of coordinates
print(plotdata)

img = plt.imread("American-style pool table diagram.png")
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 9))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 9)
ax.imshow(img, extent=[-750, 750, -400, 450], zorder=1)
x, y = zip(*plotdata)
plt.scatter(x, y, data=data, color='red', zorder=2)
```

I am facing two problems.

1. When the line `ax.imshow(img, extent=[-750, 750, -400, 450], zorder=1)` is commented out, in order to show only the coordinates, I get all the coordinates in a straight line (probably in the order that they appear in the `plotdata` list), instead of the intended locations. It looks like this:

[image: Wrong Order]

2. When the code is run as such, with the image being displayed below the plot, the labels of the axes are distorted and the entire scatter plot is compressed into a tiny area at the centre of the image.

[image: Super-Compressed]

What might be a problem with the aspect ratio of the image and how do I fix it so that the points appear as they should, in the right locations across the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is that you created 2 images. The code works fine other than that. The problem with your data points is that they are strings. But it is easy to convert them to `floats`.
Follows my code and output:

```
import random
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Conversion of dataframe to array of tuples:

data = [('-397.91', '58.91'), ('-569.73', '179.18'), ('-461.73', '306.82'), ('-199.09', '186.55'), ('-348.82', '-169.36'), ('-125.45', '-243.00'), ('4.64', '-267.55'), ('110.18', '-265.09'), ('267.27', '-12.27'), ('-687.55', '390.27')]
x = [float(i[0]) for i in data]
y = [float(i[1]) for i in data]
img = plt.imread(r"dir\icons\planet.png")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 9)
im=ax.imshow(img, extent=[-750, 750, -400, 450], zorder=1)
ax.scatter(x, y, color='red', zorder=2, s=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: example]

Comment: How does creating a new dataframe help? Why are you using a different dataset (random values for X and their sines for Y)? Is there really a need for importing Axes3D?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you had provided the data so I created my own. The problem with your data is that you have the positions as strings. But it is easy to convert them to floats. I will update the answer.